# Resize UI to fit iphone 6/6+ without using auto-layout

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I am building an ios app and I have been developing it on iphone 5 size class. I have done it this way because I have not yet learned how to use auto-layout. I was wondering if there was a way(other than auto-layout) that I can use, on this app so that the view fits perfectly in iphone 5/5c/5s and 6/6+

Comment: @ilyasUyanik I don't think he is asking how to enable the size classes, but instead how to make his UI fit on them.

Answer (score 0):

Without auto-layout the available solutions will be pretty rough.  Because your lengths are all hard values-- you will have to manually manipulate them to achieve the size you want in an iPhone 6.  It would definitely still be slightly more time consuming to apply auto-layout constraints onto all of your views-- but you would be safe from having to do this again in the future.  Hopefully you don't have too many views :)